# I need to update a table with another table

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have 2 tables with the same structure:

Table A

| primary key | extra info | data to change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | cat | 4 |
| item 2 | dog | 7 |
| item 3 | cow | 5 |

Table B

| primary key | extra info | data to change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | cat | 4 |
| item 4 | inf | 8 |

so, what i need to do is to add the numbers in the column data to change if the PK is the same AND add all items that aren't in the Table A.

Expected new Table A:

| primary key | extra info | data to change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item 1 | cat | 8 |
| item 2 | dog | 7 |
| item 3 | cow | 5 |
| item 4 | inf | 8 |

I thought that using a cursor i could do the update, but, to be honest i don't know how to create it in oracle.

The code that i have:

```
IS
nombreCientifico VARCHAR2(50);
  nombreComun VARCHAR2(50);
  color VARCHAR2(50);
  fotografia varchar2(255);
  envergadura float;
  encuentros INT;
  CURSOR cursor_a_a IS
  SELECT * FROM disp_ave
  WHERE nombreComun = disp_ave.nombreComun;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_a_a;
    LOOP
    UPDATE central_ave;
    SET encuentros = encuentros + encuentros;
    
    FETCH cursor_a_a INTO nombreComun, color, fotografia, envergadura, encuentros;
    EXIT WHEN cursor_a_a%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_a_a;
    END IF;
END;
```

i would be really thankful if you teach me how to build the cursor to solve this problem.

Comment: Use [`merge` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F). You may check examples section in the docs

Comment: i'm trying it, give me a moment

Comment: Thank you, it worked